# Wicket: access field from inner form

Tags: wicket, wicket-1.5, wicket-1.6

I have a Wicket page with this structure:

```
<form wicket:id="generalForm" method="post" class="form_recherche">
        <input value="" type="text" wicket:id="myField_1" />

        <form wicket:id="innerForm" method="post">
                <input value="" type="text" wicket:id="myField_2"/>
                <input type="submit" class="button-classic" wicket:id="accept_2"/>
        </form>

        <input type="submit" class="button-classic" wicket:id="accept_1" /> 

</form>
```

1 external form with 1 inner form. One field each. The fact is that when the "accept_2" button is clicked, the field "myField_1" is not submitted to the server (only the "myField_2" is submitted). And in fact, I would need the "field_1" field to do some validation.

What am I missing and why isn't the "myField_1" being filled on the server why "accept_2" is clicked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to override [Form#wantSubmitOnNestedFormSubmit()](https://github.com/apache/wicket/blob/59ece66624c2e4cdc407390108e028329bcef1a1/wicket-core/src/main/java/org/apache/wicket/markup/html/form/Form.java#L919) on the outer Form to return `true`. This way you will tell Wicket that you want the (outer) form to be submitted as well when one of its nested forms is submitted.

You used SO tags `wicket-1.5` and `wicket-1.6`. I am not sure whether this method is available for your version of Wicket.